# Using custom font to generate PDF from HTML on iOS 11

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, pdf

I'm trying to generate PDF file from HTML template. In general this approach works fine except for one thing. 
When I try to use custom font AvenirLTStd-Black that is included into my bundle I get empty text in PDF but it looks fine in a webView. I can't see images from my bundle also. So I can assume that UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter doesn't see my fonts files and images. 
Is my assumption correct? And is there any workaround for this?

Here is part of css:

```
 <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';
        src: url('ChampagneLimousinesItalic.ttf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Heavy';
        src: url('ChampagneLimousinesItalic.ttf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

And code for generating:

func exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: String) {
        let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()

```
    let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent)
    printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer)

    pdfFilename = "\(AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().getDocDir())/Invoice\(invoiceNumber!).pdf"
    pdfData?.write(toFile: pdfFilename, atomically: true)

    print(pdfFilename)
}
```

[Link to original tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, I want to print HTML with custom fonts in iOS. Here's my solution:

1. Load HTML string with base url(which your fonts file can be found) into UIWebView.
2. Get UIViewPrintFormatter by UIWebView's viewPrintFormatter method after the web view is loaded.
3. Use UIViewPrintFormatter to print.

Since I'm not very familiar with swift, here's some Objective-c sample code:

Load html string:

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window];
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];
[window addSubview:webView];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.hidden = YES;
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseUrl];
```

Get UIViewPrintFormatter and print:

```
#pragma UIWebViewDelegate
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    UIPrintInfo* printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.jobName = @"Print Demo";
    UIPrintInteractionController* printVC = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    printVC.printInfo = printInfo;

    UIViewPrintFormatter* htmlFormatter = [webView viewPrintFormatter];
    printVC.printFormatter = htmlFormatter;
    [printVC presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController * _Nonnull printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    }];

    webView.delegate = nil;
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```